# Why is the map content not displayed when I reopen Print Composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I just updated from QGIS 1.7 to 2.0 on Mac. When I now open a project and create a map in the print composer the content of the map is lost when I open the project again later. The settings of the stored print are still ok, but the map content is not displayed. Instead it just says "Karte wird hier gedruckt" which means "map to be printed here" in English.

Does anybody have an idea what the problem could be? It always worked fine with 1.7.

Answer (score 6):

As soon as printed/exported, the dummy text will be replaced with the real content. This is an option to turn off live map rendering e.g. for performance reasons.

Just change the mode in the properties to **Render** and you will get a live updated image.

[image]

See also http://qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/print_composer.html#adding-a-current-qg-map-canvas-to-the-print-composer

Comment: Hi Ben, you are welcome. If this was the answer you were looking for please mark it as accepted :)

Comment: For anyone searching for where the Render mode option is, check the "Main properties" section under "Item properties"